# VSTO Word 2010 getScreentip getSupertip not fired

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have a problem with my custom XML Ribbon,
The callback "onAction", "getImage" and "getEnabled" work perfectly but getScreentip and getSupertip don't work.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <qat>
      <sharedControls>
        <button id="Flag_fr-FR"
                onAction="OnActionCallback"
                getScreentip="GetScreentip"
                getSupertip="GetSupertip" 
                getImage="GetImage"/>
        <button id="Flag_en-EN"
                onAction="OnActionCallback" 
                getScreentip="GetScreentip" 
                getSupertip="GetSupertip"
                getImage="GetImage"/>
        <separator id="Sep1" insertAfterQ="FlagEn"/>
        <button id="Refresh"
                insertAfterQ="Sep1" 
                getScreentip="GetScreentip"
                getSupertip="GetSupertip"
                onAction="OnActionCallback"
                getImage="GetImage"/>
        <separator id="Sep2" insertAfterQ="Refresh"/>
        <button id="Search"
                insertAfterQ="Sep2"
                getScreentip="GetScreentip"
                getSupertip="GetSupertip"
                onAction="OnActionCallback"
                getImage="GetImage"/>
        <button id="OnScreenKeyboard" insertAfterQ="Search"
                getScreentip="GetScreentip"
                getSupertip="GetSupertip"
                onAction="OnActionCallback"
                getImage="GetImage"/>
        <button id="Logout" insertAfterQ="OSK"
                getScreentip="GetScreentip"
                getSupertip="GetSupertip"
                onAction="OnActionCallback"
                getEnabled="GetEnabled"
                getImage="GetImage"/>
      </sharedControls>
    </qat>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Code-behind :

```
public String GetScreetip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
 {
     return ("Test...");
 }

 public String GetSupertip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
 {
     return ("Test");
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have mistyped the handler name, in the xml you wrote `getScreentip="GetScreentip"` but in the code you wrote `GetScreetip` and missed the `n`

Second, for some reason Office ignore the char combination `...` so it will only display `Test`

Other than this, everything seems fine.

Example:

Ribbon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
                <group label="MyAddIn">
                    <button id="buttonAbout"
                            onAction="buttonAbout_Click" 
                            label="About" 
                            getScreentip="buttonAbout_Screentip" 
                            getSupertip="buttonAbout_Supertip" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Ribbon.cs

```
public void buttonAbout_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Id != "buttonAbout")
        return;
    // it's not advised to use MessageBox in Office Addins
    // sometimes it gets blocked by Office
    MessageBox.Show("MyAddin v1.0");
}

public string buttonAbout_Screentip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Id != "buttonAbout")
        return string.Empty;
    return "About Screentip";
}

public string buttonAbout_Supertip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Id != "buttonAbout")
        return string.Empty;
    return "About Supertip";
}
```